# Loading Tiff stack in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, imread

Here is the code I am trying to use, xxxx is the image number that is 4 digit and ranges from 0000 to 1699.

```
for i=1:1700                                    
  stack(:,:,i)=imread('UCS_xxxx.tif',i);
end
stack=uint8(stack);
```

I wonder how should I modify the loop to account for the image numbers.

Comment: Use iminfo, it returns a sttructrict of the corresponding size.

Comment: @daniel, can I something with the xxxx part where file number comes from the value of i?

Comment: The duplicate question uses `load` instead of `readim` but the problem is identical, and the answers there should show you how to solve your problem.